# Multiple versions of EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have a solution that has three projects: one project uses EntityFramework version 5 (my data access layer) the other uses version 6 (an ASP.NET MVC application). I am using binding redirect for them to co-exist. However, during runtime, I get an error for functionalities that are specific to EntityFramework 5 (DbExtensions to be exact). It looks like that on runtime the version 6 is being loaded.

Comment: Why can't you upgrade your data access layer to EF6 or downgrade your ASP.net application to EF5?

Comment: I tried. The ASP.NET MVC is using EF6 while my access layer is using DbExtensions which is specific to 5. If I could find a work around this way I would gladly do it.

Comment: Not really specific to 5 just renamed https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Design%20Meeting%20Notes%20-(March%2021%2C%202013

Comment: You're right, it's not specific to 5.

I looked up IQueryableExtensions via object browser, it's not under System.Data.Entity, am I missing something?

Comment: Or is it QueryableExtensions?

Comment: Yeah, it is QueryableExtensions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Sweet, got it! Thanks man. How do I mark your suggestion as answer? :)

Comment: No worries, added as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Dismissile suggestion upgrade your data access layer to EF6.

In EF6 the *DbExtensions* class still exists but has been renamed (see [https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Design%20Meeting%20Notes%20-(March%2021%2C%202013)](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Design%20Meeting%20Notes%20-%28March%2021%2C%202013%29) to *QueryableExtensions* (see docs [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions(v=vs.113).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)).

Comment: MS is always doing this crap.  I've been developing w MS tools for 25 years and time and again I've had to deal w assemblies that break from one version to another.  MS: Stop breaking your assemblies - you're continually making life difficult for your developers!

Comment: This isn't a solution. There are situations when you are working with a legacy DB which is supported only by EF4 or EF5 and then you have a separate DB which works with EF6. You can't upgrade DAL that you are not in control of.

Comment: Not an answer to the question.